# Error: connect ENETUNREACH when i try to connect to my NodeJS API

Tags: android, node.js, api, react-native, localhost

NodeJS is working correctly, but when I try to call it from an android app it give me that error:

Error: connect ENETUNREACH 169.254.170.254:80
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1056:14)

Thanks :)